# Input shape of a neural network

Tags: python, classification

I built a neural network, that should classify Tweets into one of four classes. But there seems to be something wrong with my input shape. The shape of train_features is (3817,4) and of train_label_onehot (3817,4), too. Test_features has the shape (784,4) and test_label_onehot (784,4). Train_label_oehot and test_label_onehot are onehot encoded target lists. This is my code:

```py
# Start neural network
network = models.Sequential()

# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(3817,)))

# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))

# Add fully connected layer with a softmax activation function for multiclass problems
network.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

network.summary()

# Compile neural network
network.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', # Cross-entropy
                optimizer='adam', # Root Mean Square Propagation
                 # Accuracy performance metric
                metrics=['accuracy'])


# Train neural network
history = network.fit(train_features, # Features
                      train_label_onehot, # Target vector, shape(3817, 4)
                      epochs=10, 
                      verbose=4, 
                      batch_size=100, # Number of observations per batch
                      validation_data=(test_features, test_label_onehot)) # Data for evaluation # test_label_onehot shape(784, 4)
```

network.summary() gives me this:

```py
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_775 (Dense)            (None, 200)               763600    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_776 (Dense)            (None, 100)               20100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_777 (Dense)            (None, 4)                 404       
=================================================================
Total params: 784,104
Trainable params: 784,104
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and the error says:

```py
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_775_input to have shape (3817,) but got array with shape (4,)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the input shape of your first layer to match the one of your data

```
# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)))
```

or more explicit

```
# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(200, activation='relu', input_dim=4))
```

or more generally

```
# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(200, activation='relu', input_dim=train_features.shape[1]))
```

Comment: This gives me the same error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)

Comment: there is no layer called `dense_10`